# How do you display data in view of a Typed DataSet (XSD)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xsd, dataset, strong-typing

I am experimenting using typed DataSet and I have a simple application using the NorthWind database called "Main.mdb" and I have a Model "MainDataSet1.xsd" that I am trying to use to list all items in an Access table called "Main".

How do I code the Index action of the HomeController to return a strongly-typed view that lists all of the Main table's contents.

```
My Home Controller:

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MainDataSet1 ds = new MainDataSet1();
            MAINTableAdapter ta = new MAINTableAdapter();

            ta.Fill(ds.MAIN);

            return View();
        }
```

Here are my options when I go to "Add>View":

```
View name: Index
Create a partial view: [unchecked]
Create a strongly-typed view: [checked]; possible options =

AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataset1;
AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1+MAINDataTable;
AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1+MAINRow;
AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1+MAINRowChangeEvent;
AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1+MAINRowChangeEventHandler;
AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1TableAdapters.MAINTableAdapter; AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager;
AdoExperiment.Models.MainDataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager+SelfReferenceComparer

Select master page: [unselected]
```

Thanks!